# The default call for fancybox does work; an extended one doesn't ...?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The default script for Fancybox to do his trick does work. See the script >

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<!-- Needs jQuery library (see above) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<txp:site_url />fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<txp:site_url />fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

But an extended script doesn't. Look at [this page](http://www.claraelders.nl/txpnew/kunst/schilderijen).  The script >

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<!-- Needs jQuery library (see above) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<txp:site_url />fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<txp:site_url />fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I know nothing about coding, so ... is there a typo or something?

Comment: are you sure you downloaded the fancybox latest version? because when I tried your code here http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/47/ and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i found out that your just missing clossing tags which is this `});` 
Your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
                    }
                }
            }
          }); // this is what youre missing
    });
```

Comment: I did look hundred times into the mirror ... @#%$@#& ... but thank you so much sir ... :)